# Error with LINQ: Sequence contains no elements

Tags: c#, multithreading, linq

Occasionally, my users experience the issue where in the log files I can see this exception is thrown (***Sequence contains no elements***)

I search around and can see this exception happens when you try to access or use aggregate on an empty list.

I searched through the code around this exception (too bad no stacktrace was logged), and the only "potential" culprit is the below lines (that use either Fist(), Last(), Single() or any Aggregate). However I can't understand why and not able reproduce on my local. Please help to advise.

```
if (data.Any())
    return data.OrderByDescending(d => d.UpdatedTime).First().UpdatedTime;
```

Here, `data` is a `List<MyObject>` and `MyObject` has `DateTime` property called `UpdatedTime`

===== More surrounding code =====

This is where I got the unhandled exception in the log. GetRecentUpdates method has its own try catch block, so ruled out.

```
public ActionResult GetUpdatedTime(long lastUpdated) {
    var data = dataAccess.GetRecentUpdates(lastUpdated);
    var html = htmlBuilder.Build(data);
    return Content(html);
}

public List<MyObject> GetRecentUpdates(long lastUpdatedInTicks) {
    var list = _cache.GetRecentRequests(_userCache.UserId);
    if (list != null) {
        var lastUpdated = new DateTime(lastUpdatedInTicks);
        list = list.Where(l => l!=null && l.UpdatedTime > lastUpdated).ToList();
    }
    return list ?? new List<MyObject>();
}

public List<MyObject> GetRecentRequests(string userId) {
     List<MyObject> requests = null;
     try {
         // simplied but the idea stays
         requests = dictionary.Get(userId);
         commonRequests = dictionary.Get("common");

         if (requests != null) {
             if (commonRequests != null)
                 requests = requests.Union(commonRequests).ToList();
         } else {
             request = commonRequests;
         }

         if (requests != null) {
             requests = requests.OrderByDescending(r => r.CreatedDateTime).ToList();
     }
     catch (Exception ex) {
         // log the exception (handled)
     }

     return requests;
}

public string Build(List<MyObject> data) {
    var lastUpdated = DateTime.MinValue;
    if (data.Any())
        lastUpdated = data.OrderByDescending(d => d.UpdatedTime).First().UpdatedTime;
    return String.Format("<tr style=\"display:none\"><td><div Id='MetaInfo' data-lastUpdated='{0}' /></td></tr>", lastUpdated.Ticks);
}
```

The javascript calls `GetUpdatedTime` every 10s. Ussually everything goes fine, but every once in awhile, this exception is thrown. Once it's thrown, it keeps being thrown every 10s until the user refreshes the page.

Comment: Do you execute this code within a multithreaded environment?

Comment: Yes, but `data` is a local variable within the method actually.

Comment: Can you show more of the surrounding code?

Comment: If data is a List<MyObject> this should work perfectly fine, so my guess is that the problem is not in the lines you posted.

Comment: and the code of dataAccess.GetRecentUpdates();? ... i'd recommend allways to use typed references ... with var you never see what you actually have

Comment: What does your `dataAccess.GetRecentUpdates` method? Are you sure that the exception is here? Did you log the stacktrace?

Comment: I added more code for GetRecentUpdates()

Comment: Log the stack trace of the exception. There's no need to *guess* where the error is happening when you can get the full stack trace :) And of course, if you just replace the `data.Any()` and `.First()` with a simple `FirstOrDefault`, you'll see it doesn't actually happen there.

Comment: Yeah it's easy for me to make that change. The problem is I don't know if I actually fix the issue or not.
I have added to log the stacktrace as well, but can't reproduce in dev environment. And ofc we don't want to wait to see it again in production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**:

Another version after some investigate: as you've said, your code is running in multhithreading environment, and the `data` object could be accessed by two or more threads. As it's a `reference` type variable, the reference of it can be modified. So, consider such situation:

First thread enters the `Build` method and checking the condition:

```
if (data.Any())
```

and the `data` isn't empty at this moment, so it enters the `true` block. **Right exactly in this time** another one thread enters the `Build` method, but on that moment the `data` variable is empty, and all reference for it points to empty `List`. But the first one thread already into the `true` block:

```
lastUpdated = data.OrderByDescending(d => d.UpdatedTime).First().UpdatedTime;
```

And it fails with you exception. And now good news: you can fix it in many ways:

- First of all, check the creating `data` logic. May be, it is a static or shared variable, or object it being populated from, is a static or shared variable, and you have race condition for this resource. You may change the logic of it's creation or wrap it into a some synchronizing primitive so the only one thread can `Build` at the same time (**but this can affect the performance of your program**).
- Change the logic of `GetRecentRequests` - can't say for sure, but I think that the situation is something like this: `commonRequests` are empty all the time, and for the first thread `dictionary` got some data, but has no data for second thread, and `data` object is being overridden and is empty. **Way to debug it**: add `Barrier` primitive to your program during test run, and wait for 10-15 threads being awaiting for the barrier. After that they'll start simultaneously build your data and error will happen with high probability (do not insert breakpoints - they'll sychronize your threads).
- Make a local copy of `data` object, something like this:

  ```
  var localData = data.Select(d => d).ToList();
  ```

Hope this helps.

---

Your code is checking, if some data is available, and after that filters the data by date. As you are using the LINQ extension methods, I think that `data` is an `IEnumerable` object, not the `List`, so, when you are calling `Any()` method, **it's being enumerated**, and after that, you are calling the `First()` method, which is **enumerating it too**.

So, if your data is being a result of some `yeild return` method, it's being enumerated once, and on second time there is no data there, and sequence is empty.

Consider to change your code to work with data as a `List` or `Array`, or use the `FirstOrDefault` method to have a `null` object if there is no data, like this:

```
//var dataList = data.OrderByDescending(d => d.UpdatedTime).ToList();
if (data.Count > 0)
    return dataList[0].UpdatedTime;
```

or

```
var firstElement = data.OrderByDescending(d => d.UpdatedTime).FirstOrDefault();
return firstElement != null ? firstElement.UpdatedTime : DateTime.MinValue;
```

Comment: Should not be the problem if data is a List<MyObject> though

Comment: @FlorianSchmidinger can be a problem if List is being calculated outside the method via `yield` if yielding bound to some event data. One event - one element of the list, not the two.

Comment: After I called `data.Any()`, I called `OrderByDescending()` so it's not actually a filter. And also `dataAccess.GetRecentUpdates(lastUpdated)` returns a List<MyObject>

Comment: @Vogel612 `Any()` is returning boolean

Comment: And if I understand your answer correctly, this exception should happen all the time, which is not my case. This only happens every once in awhile

Comment: @harry Not filter, yes, but it is another enumeration. Try to use `.Count` instead of `Any()`

Comment: @harry I think the crux is that it could also return an instance of a class deriving from List<MyObject> where, when you iterate through, the list gets cleared for a particular reason.

Answer (score 0):

Your code checks first if any element of `data` collection satisfies a predicate with `data.Any()`. Since there's no predicate, this call is equivalent to tell you if your `data` collection has elements or not.

For this reason, I don't think that the line

`return data.OrderByDescending(d => d.UpdatedTime).First().UpdatedTime;`

is the real problem, because an exception with the message `Sequence contains no elements` is thrown when some operation is performed in an empty collection. Since there're elements within `data` (and then `data.Any()` returns `true`), the exception is about another line in your code.

You should add more logging to your application, in order to get the full stacktrace of the exception and understand better which line is causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try FirstOrDefault() method.

```
var lastUpdated = DateTime.MinValue;
var first = data.OrderByDescending(d => d.UpdatedTime).FirstOrDefault();
if (first != null)
{
  lastUpdated = first.UpdatedTime;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `MyObject` definition is like. But I am guessing the 
`UpdatedTime` field is `DateTime?`. If so, it happen at last method, when:

```
lastUpdated = data.OrderByDescending(d => d.UpdatedTime).First().UpdatedTime;
return String.Format("<tr style=\"display:none\"><td><div Id='MetaInfo' data-lastUpdated='{0}' /></td></tr>", lastUpdated.Ticks);
```

Where the `UpdatedTime` is `null`, and `lastUpdated.Ticks` throw `NullReferenceException`.